# What is the url for the browser based interactive console for live appengine project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a live appengine application (myapp.appspot.com). I would like to access (python) terminal like behaviour within a browser window. I recall someone showing me functionality but cannot seem to find documentation on it. The functionality looked similar to the interactive console available in the local development environment.

Does anyone know the url at which I can access this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a handler for admin application:

```
- url: /admin.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
  login: admin
```

Then you can access interactive console at `/admin/interactive`.

Its also possible with appstats, but you also have to add `appstats_SHELL_OK = True` in your `appengine_config.py`.